# How can I uses SAS to randomly select twins?

Tags: sas

I am working with data with a mix of singletons and twins. I have separated the twins and singletons into separate groups, singles and twins. In twins, I would like to randomly select one child from each pair. The data is coded like:
InfantID    maternalid
00011-21    11
00011-22    11
00012-21    12
00012-22    12

Where each set of twins has the same 5 digits of the ID and are differentiated by '21' or '22'. The maternal id is the same for each set of twins.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Separate the ID so that you have a the first portion alone
2. Add a random digit
3. Sort by ID and random digit
4. Select first or last value

- assumes input data set name is HAVE

```
data modified;
set have;
TWIN_ID = scan(infant_id, 1, "-");
random = rand('normal', 55, 10);
run;

proc sort data=modified;
by TWIN_ID random;
run;

data selected;
set modified;
by TWIN_ID random;
if first.twin_id;
run;
```